# I want sum all item prices in all rows in the table in database that have the same item id

Tags: c#, linq

I want sum all item prices in all rows in the database table that have the same item id. I mean the result should be one number and put it on textbox automatically when I choose a specific item id from dropdownlist

How can I do it in linq?

Is this achieve what I want or should use `Group by` .

Tell me what the correct answer:

```
    public double oIlstGetVouchersDetailjh(int nvoucherID)
    {
        vouchers ovouchers = new vouchers();
        double sum = (from Entity in ovouchers.INV_InventoryItems
                                    where Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID
                                    select Entity.ItemPrice).Sum();
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: What does this query give you? What are you expecting it to give you? It looks like it should be fine, but you don't have many details on the other structure of the data.

Comment: I did not try it .. I am a beginner in Programming Especially linq

Comment: ovouchers.INV_InventoryItems.Where(x => x.ItemID == nvoucherID).Select(x => x.ItemPrice).Aggregate((x,y) => x + y);

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a new table in the database which contains the ID and the Total value.  Your current solution only gets 1 ID.  Using Group By will create totals for all id.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            vouchers ovouchers = new vouchers();
            ovouchers.INV_InventoryItems = new List<inventory>(){
               new inventory{
                   ItemID = 123, ItemPrice = 1
               },
               new inventory{
                   ItemID = 123, ItemPrice = 2
               },
               new inventory{
                   ItemID = 123, ItemPrice = 3
               },
               new inventory{
                   ItemID = 124, ItemPrice = 1
               },
               new inventory{
                   ItemID = 124, ItemPrice = 1
               },

            };

            var inventoryByID = ovouchers.INV_InventoryItems.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.ItemID, y => y.ItemPrice)
                .Select(x => new { ID = x.Key, total = x.Sum() });
            string boxID = "123";
            double itemID = inventoryByID.Where(x => x.ID == int.Parse(boxID)).Select(y => y.total).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
    public class vouchers
    {
        public List<inventory> INV_InventoryItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class inventory
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public double ItemPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
​
​
```

Comment: Hello Jdweng I want sum all itemprices in all row in the table in data base that have the same item id .....i mean the result should be one number and put it on textbox automatically when i choose specific item id from dropdownlist

Comment: I modified the code to get the price from the Group By query.  It is a trade-off to query every time you need to get the total price of an ID or do it once a create a tabular results.

Comment: i will try it after 5 hours but  is this achieved what i want ?? i wrote it in cs fill and want call it in aspx.cs how can i do this and put result on textbox.........

Comment: why you put itemprice in group by .?? i think the code you modified it  Looks like a code which I wrote in the top is true?? public double oIlstGetVouchersDetailjh(int nvoucherID)
    {
        vouchers ovouchers = new vouchers();
        double sum = (from Entity in ovouchers.INV_InventoryItems
                                    where Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID
                                    select Entity.ItemPrice).Sum();
        return sum;
    }